# How can i extract data from this? Is it Tuple or what?

Tags: python

I've faced problem with this: I recieve this list:

here is full code:

```
cl = Client()
cl.load_settings(cookie_file_path)
get_posts_by_amount = cl.user_medias(user_id=user_id, amount=10)

print(get_posts_by_amount)
#Output:
#[Media(pk='2747480339582457919',
#  id='2747480339582457919_43750503868',
#  code='CYhAs_kLpg_'), Media(...), ...]

with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(get_posts_by_amount, f) 
# Here i recieve an error
```

So i don't know what this is. I thought it is a Tuple, but I found out, that tuples don't have dicts in it. Only seperated by comma. So how can I extract dict from it Media(...)? I can use re module, but i don't like this way to solve the problem.
And what is it? Is it Tuple?

I just need to save this list of dicts in json

Here is what is receive:

```
[Media(pk='2747480339582457919', id='2747480339582457919_43750503868', code='CYhAs_kLpg_', taken_at=datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 9, 16, 20, 26, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), media_type=2, product_type='feed', thumbnail_url=HttpUrl('https://scontent-hel3-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/c0.210.540.540a/271438894_2815944505376224_6614545554878324040_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-hel3-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=1&_nc_ohc=dCWzGE0GtWYAX8bvrTS&edm=APU89FABAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=00_AT_iRpqf-Qy6-IhDK5EZhHxFkT4Snks8lZoyWCEG66UiJA&oe=61DDD204&_nc_sid=86f79a', scheme='https', host='scontent-hel3-1.cdninstagram.com', tld='com', host_type='domain', port='443', path='/v/t51.2885-15/e35/c0.210.540.540a/271438894_2815944505376224_6614545554878324040_n.jpg', query='_nc_ht=scontent-hel3-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=1&_nc_ohc=dCWzGE0GtWYAX8bvrTS&edm=APU89FABAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=00_AT_iRpqf-Qy6-IhDK5EZhHxFkT4Snks8lZoyWCEG66UiJA&oe=61DDD204&_nc_sid=86f79a'), location=None, user=UserShort(pk='43750503868', username='dom_recepts', full_name='', profile_pic_url=None, profile_pic_url_hd=None, is_private=None, stories=[]), comment_count=51, like_count=1752, has_liked=None, caption_text='Маленькая просьба, кто заберёт к себе рецепт в закладки , оставьте любой смайл в комментариях. \nХочу видеть тех, кому нравится то, что я делаю Для меня это очень важно.\n\nШикарный рецепт Картофеля в сметанном кляре.\n\nИНГРЕДИЕНТЫ \n- Картофель-1 кг\n- Сыр-150 гр\n- Яйца-2 шт\n- Сметана-100 гр\n- Мука-4 ст/л\n- Зелень\n- Черный перец\n\nВСЕ ПРИЯТНОГО АППЕТИТА!\n\nАвтор: @evgen_food_', usertags=[], video_url=HttpUrl('https://scontent-hel3-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t50.2886-16/10000000_164694035882501_5421990776812161903_n.mp4?_nc_ht=scontent-hel3-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=105&_nc_ohc=XVcL2thpzFYAX8fLQKf&edm=APU89FABAAAA&ccb=7-4&oe=61DD9EFB&oh=00_AT8GuqUTcMgAHmjdMXE082d7tzPFS_18y7_XyJsnsHCq1g&_nc_sid=86f79a', scheme='https', host='scontent-hel3-1.cdninstagram.com', tld='com', host_type='domain', port='443', path='/v/t50.2886-16/10000000_164694035882501_5421990776812161903_n.mp4', query='_nc_ht=scontent-hel3-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=105&_nc_ohc=XVcL2thpzFYAX8fLQKf&edm=APU89FABAAAA&ccb=7-4&oe=61DD9EFB&oh=00_AT8GuqUTcMgAHmjdMXE082d7tzPFS_18y7_XyJsnsHCq1g&_nc_sid=86f79a'), view_count=30376, video_duration=0.0, title='', resources=[], clips_metadata={}), Media(pk='2747386045588816880', id='2747386045588816880_43750503868', code='CYgrQ1cL8Pw', taken_at=datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 9, 13, 13, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), media_type=2, product_type='feed', thumbnail_url=HttpUrl('https://scontent-hel3-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/c0.90.720.720a/s640x640/271498407_651228016051780_1613734865107275564_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-hel3-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=104&_nc_ohc=vaTlvIEvjsoAX_kgLDO&tn=7CPk5P_ZtMf00PPB&edm=APU89FABAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=00_AT8Vu68Bshdg4evzRpCtunbwQv8HC2-sSPEVYUj0GCm6vw&oe=61DDC2D0&_nc_sid=86f79a', scheme='https', host='scontent-hel3-1.cdninstagram.com', tld='com', host_type='domain', port='443', path='/v/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/c0.90.720.720a/s640x640/271498407_651228016051780_1613734865107275564_n.jpg', query='_nc_ht=scontent-hel3-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=104&_nc_ohc=vaTlvIEvjsoAX_kgLDO&tn=7CPk5P_ZtMf00PPB&edm=APU89FABAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=00_AT8Vu68Bshdg4evzRpCtunbwQv8HC2-sSPEVYUj0GCm6vw&oe=61DDC2D0&_nc_sid=86f79a'), location=None, user=UserShort(pk='43750503868', username='dom_recepts', full_name='', profile_pic_url=None, profile_pic_url_hd=None, is_private=None, stories=[]), comment_count=25, like_count=910, has_liked=None, caption_text='Маленькая просьба, кто заберёт к себе рецепт в закладки , оставьте любой смайл в комментариях. \nХочу видеть тех, кому нравится то, что я делаю Для меня это очень важно.\n\nШАВЕРМА ПО-ПИТЕРСКИ\n\nПолучилось очень сочно, и вкусно!\nМне очень интересно, а какие ингредиенты добавляете вы?\n\nИнгредиенты:\nКура грудка 700 гр\nЛаваш 2 уп\nОгурцы 100 гр\nТомат 200 гр\nКапуста красная 150 гр\n\nСоус:\nСметана 450 гр 20%\nОгурцы 100 гр\nПетрушка 20 гр\nЧеснок 3 зуб\nСоль перец по вкусу \nПриправы восточные(Зира, куркума, мускатный орех.)\n\nГрамовки на 3 шавермы\n\nПриготовление:\nПервым делаем соус, в сметану добавляем, мелко нарезаный чеснок, огурец соломкой, или кубиком, солим, перчим по вкусу, добавляем немного сока лимона, восточные пряности, рубленную любимую зелень, и все перемешиваем, соус готов. \nДальше делаем мясо, куриную грудку, разрезаем пополам вдоль,  обжариваем в растительном масле, на среднем огне с двух сторон, у меня ушло примерно 8-10 минут, параллельно подготавливаем Овощи, нарезаем, огурец, томат, красную капусту соломкой, и укладываем на лаваш, поливаем сверху соусом, не жалеем, и укладываем курочку, заворачиваем шаверму, и жарим на сковородке на огне чуть выше среднего, со всех сторон. Шаверма «По-Питерски» готова, получилось очень сочно, и безумно вкусно \n\nАвтор: @yurakorolyov', usertags=[], video_url=HttpUrl('https://scontent-hel3-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t50.2886-16/271313094_1075010066687689_2816304714935862078_n.mp4?_nc_ht=scontent-hel3-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=101&_nc_ohc=88u3c6UNnZ4AX9TtHgx&edm=APU89FABAAAA&ccb=7-4&oe=61DD6B8A&oh=00_AT8q2CO_U6wcdzXn84FRf9Vspqa3BNTh0R_0Rg0pQHFAtg&_nc_sid=86f79a', scheme='https', host='scontent-hel3-1.cdninstagram.com', tld='com', host_type='domain', port='443', path='/v/t50.2886-16/271313094_1075010066687689_2816304714935862078_n.mp4', query='_nc_ht=scontent-hel3-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=101&_nc_ohc=88u3c6UNnZ4AX9TtHgx&edm=APU89FABAAAA&ccb=7-4&oe=61DD6B8A&oh=00_AT8q2CO_U6wcdzXn84FRf9Vspqa3BNTh0R_0Rg0pQHFAtg&_nc_sid=86f79a'), view_count=22874, video_duration=0.0, title='', resources=[], clips_metadata={}), Media(pk='2747191543456408027', id='2747191543456408027_43750503868', code='CYf_CdNrSHb', taken_at=datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 9, 6, 46, 32, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), media_type=2, product_type='feed', thumbnail_url=HttpUrl('https://scontent-hel3-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/c0.90.720.720a/s640x640/271417103_622015262384802_4377970746578351557_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-hel3-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=106&_nc_ohc=sza0yKC3bRMAX9pQJlr&edm=APU89FABAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=00_AT8QyikKQ0mk7hJgsPiFEpLwtW1UOfwdAv5joXH7vPdrbA&oe=61DD6B4E&_nc_sid=86f79a', scheme='https', host='scontent-hel3-1.cdninstagram.com', tld='com', host_type='domain', port='443', path='/v/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/c0.90.720.720a/s640x640/271417103_622015262384802_4377970746578351557_n.jpg', query='_nc_ht=scontent-hel3-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=106&_nc_ohc=sza0yKC3bRMAX9pQJlr&edm=APU89FABAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=00_AT8QyikKQ0mk7hJgsPiFEpLwtW1UOfwdAv5joXH7vPdrbA&oe=61DD6B4E&_nc_sid=86f79a'), location=None, user=UserShort(pk='43750503868', username='dom_recepts', full_name='', profile_pic_url=None, profile_pic_url_hd=None, is_private=None, stories=[]), comment_count=60, like_count=1573, has_liked=None, caption_text='Маленькая просьба, кто заберёт к себе рецепт в закладки , оставьте любой смайл в комментариях. \nХочу видеть тех, кому нравится то, что я делаю Для меня это очень важно.\n\nМАННИК НА МОЛОКЕ\n⠀\nМанник - моя отдельная любовь❤️\n⠀\nСохраняйте еще один вариант вкусного, нежного манника, который готовится проще простого, а главное быстро \n⠀\nИнгредиенты:\n⠀\n✴️ Яйца - 2 шт\n✴️ Сахар - 150 г\n✴️ Ванилин\n✴️ Масло растительное - 80 г\n✴️ Манка - 200 г\n✴️ Молоко - 340 мл\n✴️ Масло сливочное - 20 г\n✴️ Мука - 100 г\n✴️ Разрыхлитель - 10 г\n⠀\nПриготовление:\n⠀\nЯйца хорошо взбиваем с сахаром с помощью венчика, затем вливаем растительное масло, перемешиваем до однородности и добавляем ванилин.\n⠀\nМолоко нагреваем на плите или в микроволновой печи (не доводя до кипения), добавляем сливочное масло и перемешиваем до его растворения. Затем сюда же добавляем манную крупу и хорошо перемешиваем.\nВливаем яичную смесь в молочную и хорошо перемешиваем. Оставляем на минут 20-30 для набухания манки.\n⠀\nЧерез пол часа просеиваем муку с разрыхлителем и замешиваем тесто. Вливаем в форму (у меня d-18 см) и выпекаем при 180 градусах 40 минут.\n⠀\nПриятного аппетита \n\nАвтор: @elya_culinary', usertags=[], video_url=HttpUrl('https://scontent-hel3-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t50.2886-16/271255680_595940601480668_4445328583849392272_n.mp4?_nc_ht=scontent-hel3-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=108&_nc_ohc=6F7_CwTK-noAX_9q6QY&edm=APU89FABAAAA&ccb=7-4&oe=61DD3B51&oh=00_AT8dMIfZYhN2cZtrrDDqrffIEdca-pSuIvkyaSUTMnLfZA&_nc_sid=86f79a', scheme='https', host='scontent-hel3-1.cdninstagram.com', tld='com', host_type='domain', port='443', path='/v/t50.2886-16/271255680_595940601480668_4445328583849392272_n.mp4', query='_nc_ht=scontent-hel3-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=108&_nc_ohc=6F7_CwTK-noAX_9q6QY&edm=APU89FABAAAA&ccb=7-4&oe=61DD3B51&oh=00_AT8dMIfZYhN2cZtrrDDqrffIEdca-pSuIvkyaSUTMnLfZA&_nc_sid=86f79a'), view_count=25487, video_duration=0.0, title='', resources=[], clips_metadata={})]
```

P.S.
Excuse me my English. I am not native

Comment: Please post **VALID** python code.

Comment: @balderman There was a formatting issue which I've now fixed. It's still incomplete, but at least it's syntactically valid.

Comment: Hi, sorry . Is this better now?

Comment: It's a list of Media objects, you'll need to convert each Media object into a dict, then you can use json module to turn it into json.  I assume this is django?

Comment: It's an object of type `Media`

Comment: Where does it come from? I am afraid the tool that log it truncates it so you cannot parse it with 100% percent sure you get correct result

Comment: The code in the post is **not** a valid python code. Start by posting valid python code.

Comment: what is not valid with that @balderman? It's valid but not complete, please add your Media class too

Comment: I don't really know what this is. I am just using library for instagram parsing. That's all @ little_birdie

Comment: @kosciej16 Did you try to run it? Does it run?

Comment: Read the library's documentation.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. `Media` is not defined, so how do you expect us to know what it is? Please [edit] to add its definition. For reference, see [mre]. For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: If you don't know what an object is use `help(object)` or print all it's attributes with `pprint.pprint(vars(object))` . The `pprint` package is included with `python3`.

Comment: I have updated my question with full code

Comment: Thanks, I will see search this

Comment: @Anton_Kozlov That's not the full code. To start, `Client` is not defined. And are you sure the printed output contains `get_posts_by_amount = `? That doesn't make much sense unless the library you're using is doing runtime variable inspection.

Comment: You need to understand the Media class, you cannot just convert it to json without understanding what is in it.  Look in the documentation for the system you are working with, or look at the source code.. to understand what is being returned.

Comment: @ wjandrea. You are right. II wanted to type output. But it's really full code. Client is defined by cookie file. Or you are asking me about library?

Comment: `Client, cookie_file_path, user_id` are not defined, as well as `import json`. You need to make a [mre] including complete but minimal code, minimal example input, expected output (JSON), and actual output, including the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341).

Comment: Yeah, I understood. But I just wanted to know what is this: Media(...). Is it a tuple or something. Tried to search object media in python and found nothing. I thought it wouldn't be so complicated)

Comment: I just want to replace Media(...) with {...}

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer! The library was using modules from pydantic
https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/exporting_models/

So the answer on my question would be:

For json: `get_posts_by_amount[0].json()`

For dict: `get_posts_by_amount[0].dict()`